# Postfix SASL SMTP

Tags: postfix, smtp, telnet, courier

I am getting an issue when trying to send out email on 465  secure SMTP with a Postfix + Courier with MySQL virtual users. I am able to connect with IMAP secure and download, and I can also send mail on Port 25 unsecured. I am trying to use SASL for the outgoing. When I try to telnet port 465 its refused. When I try to send a message I get this in the /var/log/mail.log

```
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: connect from pool-74-111-178-60.pitbpa.fios.verizon.net[74.111.178.60]
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: warning: pool-74-111-178-60.pitbpa.fios.verizon.net[74.111.178.60]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: warning: SASL authentication problem: unknown password verifier
Apr 2 00:24:34 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: warning: pool-74-111-178-60.pitbpa.fios.verizon.net[74.111.178.60]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: no mechanism available
Apr 2 00:24:35 Lucid postfix/smtpd[3714]: disconnect from pool-74-111-178-60.pitbpa.fios.verizon.net[74.111.178.60]

/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf - http://74.111.178.60/random/smtpd.conf

/etc/postfix/main.cf - http://74.111.178.60/random/main.cf
```

Comment: /etc/postfix/master.cf - http://74.111.178.60/random/master.cf

/etc/default/saslauthd - http://74.111.178.60/random/saslauthd

/etc/pam.d/smtp - http://74.111.178.60/random/smtp

Answer (score 1):

Check MECHANISMS in your `random/smtpd.conf` file first. On my OS it's `/etc/default/saslauthd`.

I use PAM authentication, test it first with a login from `/etc/passwd` as it seems to be set to PAM. Also to keep it simple you can try using SASL over port 25, it's is pretty good too.

Create this directory if it doesn't exist: `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd/` for spooling.

My `/etc/default/saslauthd` looks like this. Hopefully your error is as simple as changing `MECHANISMS="pam"` to `mysql` or similar:

```
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="pam"
MECH_OPTIONS=""
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd -r"
```

Comment: Even with a different flavour of OS I'd still try PAM or similar authentication first.